# ImportError: unknown location

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to access Jupyter files on a Google Cloud cluster from Python. I would need the google.cloud.dataproc_v1 package to do this but every time I try:

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1
```

or

```
import google.cloud.dataproc_v1
```

(which is what Google has on their documentation) I get this error: 
n 
    from google.cloud import dataproc_v1
ImportError: cannot import name 'dataproc_v1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Why is this happening and how can I get it to import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-dataproc
```

or

```
python2 -m pip install google-cloud-dataproc
```